# In special relativity, is mass considered as $\gamma m$ or is only the momentum considered as $\gamma mv$?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, mass, mass-energy

I am trying to solve the equation of motion of free-falling object considering relativistic effects.
I am not sure the force on the object is whether $\gamma mg$ or just $mg$ where $m$ is the rest mass and $g$ is the magnitude of constant gravitational field.

My highschool teacher taught me a brief reason why the momentum of moving object should be corrected as $\gamma mv$.

And in the book about relativity by Einstein, I saw a proof of $E=\gamma m$.

So, is only the momentum and energy of a moving particle multiplied by $\gamma$? or the mass itself has been multiplied? Is the gravitational mass, i.e., the thing that is multiplied to the magnitude of the gravitational field in the gravitational force term, $\gamma m$ or just $m$?

Comment: Newton's law of gravitation is not consistent with special relativity. That's the whole reason that general relativity was developed. You need to clarify what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: Might be good to state that you are working with $c =1$ here. Also, I am not sure how I would approach a question in special relativity where the particle feels a newtonian gravitational force.

Comment: @Prahar I am considering an object in a constant downward gravitational field.(ordinary freefall) Is the field that exerts force on the object effected by the object itself?

Comment: Look at this post to see how newton's second law is extended to special relativity: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/586867/relativistic-version-of-newtons-2nd-law. This partially answers the question because you immediately wrote down $ F = mg$ which is an incorrect application of the non-relativistic version.

Comment: @JohnA. I am not working with $c=1$ because I am not yet familiar with those. The expression $E=\gamma m$ that I've used is just a copy from the book which used c=1 unit system. It would be thankful if you answer ignoring c=1.

Comment: @JohnA. So, is it fine to write force as $F=\gamma^3 ma$? For example, $\gamma^3 ma=\gamma mg$

Answer (score 4):

> I am not sure the force on the object is whether γmg or just mg where m is the rest mass and g is the magnitude of constant gravitational field.

In relativity the force on a free falling object is 0. This follows from the equivalence principle which says that an object in free fall is equivalent to an object remaining at rest in an inertial frame. An object remaining at rest in an inertial frame experiences no force.

See the Veritasium video “[Why gravity is not a force](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XRr1kaXKBsU)” for a decent pop-sci summary or Sean Carroll’s “[Lecture Notes on General Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019)” (chapter 4) for a good textbook presentation.

> So, is only the momentum and energy of a moving particle multiplied by γ? or the mass itself has been multiplied?

In modern relativity mass is always the invariant mass. The old concept of relativistic mass has been discarded by the scientific community for several decades. The old concept of relativistic mass is redundant with the total energy.

> the thing that is multiplied to the magnitude of the gravitational field in the gravitational force term, γm or just m?

Again, the gravitational force is 0 in relativity.

In relativity Newton’s 2nd law can be written $$F^\mu = m A^\mu$$ where $F^\mu$ is the net relativistic version of force, called the four-force, $A^\mu$ is the four-acceleration, and $m$ is the invariant mass. This is another reason that the concept of relativistic mass is discarded. The relativistic form of Newton’s 2nd law uses the invariant mass.

For an object in free fall since $F^\mu=0$ then by Newton’s 2nd law $A^\mu=0$ also. This means that an accelerometer attached to an object in free fall reads 0, which can be easily verified experimentally.

The acceleration of a free-falling object is a coordinate acceleration, due to using a non-inertial frame. In that sense, gravity is locally like a fictitious force, such as the centrifugal force in a rotating reference frame. If we are interested in this fictitious force, then we can determine it using what are called the Christoffel symbols. Every coordinate system in every spacetime has a set of Christoffel symbols. They do not always have a clear interpretation, but that is where things like the centrifugal force and the Coriolis force appear.

Newton's law can be written in terms of [Christoffel symbols and coordinate time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Equivalent_mathematical_expression_using_coordinate_time_as_parameter) where $x^t=t$ as $$F^\mu - m\ \Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\alpha}{dt}\frac{dx^\beta}{dt} +m\ \Gamma^t{}_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\alpha}{dt}\frac{dx^\beta}{dt}\frac{dx^\mu}{dt}=m\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{dt^2}$$Note that in this expression the terms with the Christoffel symbols, $\Gamma$, cancel out when $\mu=t$.

Locally, by the equivalence principle, an observer at rest in a gravitational field can use the Rindler metric which represents and accelerated observer away from gravity. For the Rindler metric in Koetler Moller coordinates, the only non-zero Christoffel symbols are: $$\Gamma^t{}_{ty}=\Gamma^t{}_{yt}=\frac{g}{c^2+g y}$$$$\Gamma^y{}_{tt}=g+\frac{g^2 y}{c^2}$$ Substituting in these Christoffel symbols and $F^\mu=0$ we get your desired equation of motion which is only valid locally near the origin: $$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=-\left( g+\frac{g^2 y}{c^2}\right)+2\left( \frac{g}{c^2 + g y} \right)\left(\frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2 $$$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=2\left(\frac{g}{c^2+gy}\right)\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dy}{dt}$$$$\frac{d^2 z}{dt^2}=2\left(\frac{g}{c^2+gy}\right)\frac{dz}{dt}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of argument, let us assume that the object in question is feeling a constant force $\vec{F}$ of unknown origin (could be electromagnetic etc...) just so we can ignore the complications of gravity and special relativity here. To find the equation of motion we start with $$\vec{F} = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$$ where $t$ is time in some inertial frame. As done in the [linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/586867/relativistic-version-of-newtons-2nd-law/586876#586876) post, $$
\vec{F} = \gamma m_0 \frac{d {\vec{v}}}{dt} + \frac{d\gamma}{dt} m_0 {\vec{v}}
$$ where $m_0$ is the rest mass of the particle. From here, just plug in the definition of $\gamma$ and let us treat everything in $1$D,
$$F = \gamma m_0 \frac{d {v}}{dt} + m_0v\frac{d}{dt}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}}} $$where the dimension chosen is just whatever the trajectory of the free fall is (this is to fully general but it doesn't change the essence of the question). The resulting equation is, in some form, the ODE needed to solve to get the trajectory of the particle. Look on the linked post for some more discussion about the mass.

Take the derivative to get a more "normal looking" ODE. I cannot guarantee that it is solvable. Treat $F$ as just some number here.

Also, as the answer above has suggested, its no longer common to think of mass other than rest mass in special relativity (so much so that I never heard of relativistic mass).